# OBIEE 12c display images in column in Case Statement

Tags: oracle11g, obiee

I am looking to create a tabular report in OBIEE 12c, with images in one column. The images are uploaded in same folder, where the report is saved.

I have four columns (ID, City, Temperature, Icon) in my report.
The data type for 'Icon' column is Image Url i.e. (-> Column Properties -> Data Format -> Image URL).

The images need to be displayed using the following CASE statement. The 'Edit Formula' box of Icon column contains the following code.

```
CASE
WHEN "TD_CITY"."Temperature" > 35 THEN @html"<img src=""hot.jpg"">"
WHEN "TD_CITY"."Temperature" <= 35 THEN @html"<img src=""moderate.jpg"">"
END
```

The above code is not working. How can I achieved the above results? Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a column and set the formula to be a constant (1) then use conditional formatting to set an icon based on the value of the temperature column.
You can upload images directly via the select image button in the conditional format dialog.

## More Info

The issue is that images added the webcat are not accessible via a URL.  You need to have them served by a webserver.   The easiest way to do this is as above where you just upload a custom image (this actually uploads them to a hidden folder of `/Catalog Root/Shared Folders/custom/images`

As it turns out BI actually turns this into a download call of `saw.dll?downloadFile&Path=%2fshared%2fcustom%2fimages%2ffile.jpg` I did a quick check and it doesn't look like you can change the path to point at a different location and you probably wouldn't want to.

There are better ways of using custom resources but they get more complicated.    Take a look at https://gianniceresa.com/2016/12/deploy-custom-folder-obiee-12c-analyticsres/ for one way of making resources available in BI